# Some folders on KDE Desktop does not follow accent color

Tags: debian, kde, desktop-environment, desktop, appearance

Using Debian 12 with KDE Plasma 5.27.5, I went to System Settings -> Appearance -> Colors and set my accent color to purple, so my folders and highlighted stuff looks in that color, but some (unpreviewed?) folders in the desktop remain as the default blue.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a setting I'm forgetting to switch or is this a bug? If not, how can I fix it?

Thanks